# Parse Json string and sort based on property in C#

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I am working on a window app in which a json string like

```
{
"0":{"UID":"3182713a-60de-4576-ad82-6804d2acf2b7","Rating":-1},
"1":{"UID":"eb41478e-e9bc-428e-8203-482f6a329666","Rating":-13},
"2":{"UID":"a0922817-e706-4478-8995-d258bada488d","Rating":6.0033992049},
"3":{"UID":"e0716752-56f4-49af-a811-ae55c69baa3d","Rating":-4.9836395671},
"4":{"UID":"ec6bf376-17b5-4a9e-92be-990557551cd0","Rating":-7.754526396}
}
```

I want to parse and sort it by rating. Please suggest how i can achieve it.

Comment: Is the first key (the number) dynamic or static?

Comment: Its dynamic, its the index of the records so its not in my control.and also i am not able to change or convert it. @JamieR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to deseralise the JSON into a `Dictionary<int, YourClass>`

Example:

```
var json = @"{
""0"":{""UID"":""3182713a-60de-4576-ad82-6804d2acf2b7"",""Rating"":-1},
""1"":{""UID"":""eb41478e-e9bc-428e-8203-482f6a329666"",""Rating"":-13},
""2"":{""UID"":""a0922817-e706-4478-8995-d258bada488d"",""Rating"":6.0033992049},
""3"":{""UID"":""e0716752-56f4-49af-a811-ae55c69baa3d"",""Rating"":-4.9836395671},
""4"":{""UID"":""ec6bf376-17b5-4a9e-92be-990557551cd0"",""Rating"":-7.754526396}
}";


var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int,MyCustomClass>>(json);
```

**MyCustomClass**

```
public class MyCustomClass
{
    public Guid UID {get;set;}
    public decimal Rating {get;set;}
}
```

In the `Dictionary<int, MyCustomClass>` the `int` is the numeric key in your Json.

Note: I am using [Newtonsoft Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) here.

Once you have done the above you can sort it like the following using LINQ:

```
var sorted = result.OrderBy(x => x.Value.Rating);
// OR
var sorted = result.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Rating);
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie this works fine but how do i sort it based on Rating?

Comment: Updated I forgot about the sort!

Comment: Thanks Jamie, Thanks for the help.

Comment: @sagar43 no problem!